# Customise colors on Datepicker Dialog and change tabs on selecting a date

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, datepicker

I'm using borax12 materialdaterangepicker and want to know how I can change the colours to customise the dialog calendar and also when the user selects a date change to the To tab?

[image]

Code:

```
    // Show a datepicker when the dateButton is clicked
    dateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            to = Calendar.getInstance();
            DatePickerDialog dpd = com.borax12.materialdaterangepicker.date.DatePickerDialog.newInstance(
                    Tab2.this,
                    to.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                    to.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    to.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
            );
            dpd.setAutoHighlight(mAutoHighlight);
            dpd.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "Datepickerdialog");
            dpd.setYearRange(2016, 2017);
            dpd.isThemeDark();
        }
    });

    return v;
}
```

1). Change colours, background where the green is and maybe the tabs where the FROM and TO are and also the text. I can probably work all this out if I know how to start customising it.

2) When the user selects a day on the calender then switch to the To tab.

Comment: Isn't the date picker using your app theme colors? Primary, accent colors?

Comment: Also please give the link for the library source code

Comment: Thanks no it's not using my Primary colours, I have different colours set in colours.xml so not sure where it's getting the green from. https://github.com/borax12/MaterialDateRangePicker

Comment: Text colour is being used from styles.xml

Comment: See this link for theme, your library is based on this library and using this link to library's theme https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker/blob/master/README.md#theme-the-pickers

Comment: This is good thanks, I've used the dpd.setThemeDark(true). do you know how I can change the colour of the selected tabs? The line which appears when a tab is selected?

Comment: Its actually the accent color I think you have to override the theme in styles.xml to completely customize the colors